# Python - Find indices of a specific value in a list which is store in a 3D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following numpy array :

```
array([[[0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]],

   [[0, 0, 0],
    [0, [1, 2], 0],
    [0, 0, 0]],

   [[0, 0, 0],
    [0, 3, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]]], dtype=object)
```

The integer values are vectors pointing to coordinates. If the coordinates are close, I have to store more than one vector in a given position in my matrix. That's why I have a list [1, 2] at the position i=1, j=1 and k=1 in my array.

I am able to find the indices of the vector 3 using :

```
np.where(a == 3)
Out[67]: (array([2], dtype=int64), array([1], dtype=int64), array([1], dtype=int64))
```

But if I do the same with vector 1 or 2, I don't have any results :

```
np.where(a == 1)
Out[68]: (array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64))

np.where(a == 2)
Out[69]: (array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64))
```

How can I extract that information ?

Thank you !

Comment: I would strongly recommend reorganizing your data so you're not trying to stuff lists into arrays. That's a performance killer and a giant headache to work with in many, many ways.

Comment: Is there another way to store more than one value in an array then ?

Comment: What do you mean by: `If the coordinates are close, I have to store more than one vector in a given position in my matrix. `?

Comment: Try to find a way to reorganize your data so you're not trying to stuff two values into one array cell.

Comment: Well if I have : 
c1 (x1 = 1.5, y1 = 1.5, z1 = 1.5)
c2 (x1 = 1.6, y1 = 1.6, z1 = 1.8)

I want to store 1 and 2 in my matrix at the indices i=1, j=1, k=1. The matrix is just a division of the space.

Comment: If you are going to be putting *lists* in your array, thereby necessitating `dtype=object`, you *might as well just use a list of lists. It will be more performant

Comment: Because I want after that to find all the neighbours of a given coordinates but I don't want to calculate the distance between my given coordinates and all the others.

Comment: Then I would like to sort them in a matrix and then only work with the indices. My guess is that is faster.

Comment: If you're trying to work with spatial data, you may find dedicated spatial data structures more useful. For example, a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), provided by SciPy as [`scipy.spatial.cKDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html).

Comment: Thank you @user2357112 ! k-d tree is very nice in my situation !